# How to Remove ReadOnly Attribute on File Using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-1.0, scripting

How can I remove the ReadOnly attribute on a file, using a PowerShell (version 1.0) script?

Answer (score 148, accepted):

You can use `Set-ItemProperty`:

```
Set-ItemProperty file.txt -name IsReadOnly -value $false
```

or shorter:

```
sp file.txt IsReadOnly $false
```

Comment: Set-Property is the only built-in way you can cleanly do it on the pipeline, and using wildcards: {  sp *.txt IsReadOnly $false  }  OR { ls . -recurse -include *.cs | sp -name IsReadOnly -value $false }

Comment: Using PowerShell v2 I'm seeing hard-to-use CmdLet bindngs for sp.  PSCX Set-Writable and Set-ReadOnly don't have those problems.  I'll blog the problems I'm seeing and link to it later.  I recommend Keith's answer for PowerShell v2 (modern PowerShell).

Comment: @yzorg: So what exactly are you telling me here? As for Keith's answer, he's using PSCX. Not everyone has those installed and that's not really a case of PowerShell v1 vs. v2.

Answer (score 18):

```
$file = Get-Item "C:\Temp\Test.txt"

if ($file.attributes -band [system.IO.FileAttributes]::ReadOnly)  
{  
  $file.attributes = $file.attributes -bxor [system.IO.FileAttributes]::ReadOnly    
}
```

The above code snippet is taken from this [article](http://www.skyeagle.net/blog/post/Managing-Podcasts-with-Powershell-(Part-2).aspx)

**UPDATE**
Using [Keith Hill's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/99491/keith-hill) implementation from the comments (I have tested this, and it does work), this becomes:

```
$file = Get-Item "C:\Temp\Test.txt"

if ($file.IsReadOnly -eq $true)  
{  
  $file.IsReadOnly = $false   
}
```

Comment: The implementation is simpler than that: $file.IsReadOnly = $false

Answer (score 16):

Even though it's not *Native* PowerShell, one can still use the simple [Attrib](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490868.aspx) command for this:

```
attrib -R file.txt
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me:
dir . -r *.cs | % { $_.fullname } | % { attrib -r $_ }

Comment: Could have skipped a step: dir . -r *.cs | % { attrib -r $_.FullName }

Answer (score 12):

or you can simply use:

```
get-childitem *.cs -Recurse -File | % { $_.IsReadOnly=$false }
```

Above will work for all .cs files in sub-tree of current folder. If you need other types included then simply adjust "*.cs" to your needs.

Comment: Adjust the command (add -File) to only work with files. Directories do not have the property.

Answer (score 7):

If you happen to be using the [PowerShell Community Extensions](http://pscx.codeplex.com):

```
PS> Set-Writable test.txt
PS> dir . -r *.cs | Set-Writable
# Using alias swr
PS> dir . -r *.cs | swr
```

You can do the opposite like so:

```
PS> dir . -r *.cs | Set-ReadOnly
# Using alias sro
PS> dir . -r *.cs | sro
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Shell("net share sharefolder=c:\sharefolder/GRANT:Everyone,FULL")
Shell("net share sharefolder= c:\sharefolder/G:Everyone:F /SPEC B")
Shell("Icacls C:\sharefolder/grant Everyone:F /inheritance:e /T")
Shell("attrib -r +s C:\\sharefolder\*.* /s /d", AppWinStyle.Hide)
```

thanks for anybody who are helping to solved some problem...and helping this code

this code is working for me.. to share a folder to every one with read and write permission
you can use this in .net

Answer (score 1):

None of the solutions above change the READONLY status of folders and files but this PowerShell [script](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1z1Zix46K0z1VGQmPtThbcn7ecOeg3A-U/view?usp=sharing) does based on the following powershell commands.

Query the READONLY status of a folder (via the DirectoryInfo object)

```
$roStatus = $dirInfo.Attributes -match 'ReadOnly'
```

Change the READONLY status of a folder (via the DirectoryInfo object)

```
$dirInfo.Attributes += 'ReadOnly'
$dirInfo.Attributes -= 'ReadOnly'
```

Query the READONLY status of a file (using the file name)

```
$roStatus = Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path $strFileName -Name IsReadOnly
```

Change the READONLY status of a file (using the file name)

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path $strFileName -Name IsReadOnly -Value $false
```

Comment: DO NOT use += or -= because it will do calculations on the attribute value and result in wrong attribute if any other bit is set already leading to files that seem to disappear or have entirely different flags set.