# Remove last line from file with Powershell

Tags: powershell, text, csv

I am using

```
gc FileWithEmptyLines.txt | where {$_ -ne ""} > FileWithNoEmptyLines.txt
```

to remove the empty lines that SSRS puts at the bottom of my CSVs.

However, the last line, which has data on it, ends with a CRLF (as viewed in Notepad++) - and this is not removed, so technically there is still a blank line at the bottom of the file.

Is there a way to remove this CRLF from the last line (and keep the data intact, of course)?

Comment: That's not "technically". Unless the file ends with CR LF CR LF, there is no blank line at the end. Technically.

Comment: Ignacio, that depends on whether you understand it as a line *separator* or a line *terminator* ;)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you already know that the very last thing of the file is a CRLF you want to get rid of (and you know the encoding too) you can go the quick route:

```
$stream = [IO.File]::OpenWrite('foo.txt')
$stream.SetLength($stream.Length - 2)
$stream.Close()
$stream.Dispose()
```

This is an in-place truncation of the file. It works without reading all the file into memory (very nice if you have a *very* large file). It works for ASCII, Latin-* and UTF-8. It won't work that way for UTF-16 (you'd have to remove four bytes from the end, in that case).

You can include an additional check that the last two bytes are *really* what you want to remove:

```
$stream = [IO.File]::Open('foo.txt', [IO.FileMode]::Open)
$stream.Position = $stream.Length - 2
$bytes = 0..1 | %{ $stream.ReadByte() }
$compareBytes = 13,10 # CR,LF
if ("$bytes" -eq "$compareBytes") {
    $stream.SetLength($stream.Length - 2)
}
$stream.Close()
$stream.Dispose()
```

Again, adapt if you use another encoding, e.g. for UTF-16 you need to compare to either `0,10,0,13` or `10,0,13,0`.

Agreed, this is not very PowerShell-ey, but ever since I had to process a 700-MiB database dump I am wary of reading potentially large files into memory completely ;)

Comment: This looks like a good solution but I am getting this error:

Exception calling "SetLength" with "1" argument(s): "Non-negative number required.
Parameter name: value"
At line:2 char:18
+ $stream.SetLength <<<< ($stream.Length - 2)
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException

Comment: Well, it sounds like you're doing it on a file that is empty (which in the first example could be one that didn't exist beforehand).

Comment: Can't really reproduce that here. The code worked for me and correctly removed the last two bytes, in the latter example only if they were indeed CRLF.

Comment: I got it working...the filename in the first line HAD to be fully qualified ("C:\File.txt"). Thanks!

Comment: In my case, this is only removing a few characters, not really removing the whole last line.

Comment: You can check the file encoding (for non-binary files) with the [function here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77559509/1147688). Or just use the simpler UTF-16/32 regex part from same function.

Answer (score 10):

When you read a file using `Get-Content` it streams each line down the pipe as a string. When `Out-File` (essentially what `>` is an alias for) gets these strings, it always appends a line terminator sequence.  Try the following if the files are not too big:

```
$text = [IO.File]::ReadAllText("c:\FileWithEmptyLinesAtEnd.txt")
[IO.File]::WriteAllText("c:\FileWithEmptyLinesAtEnd.txt", $text.TrimEnd())
```

This is the file before:

```
14> fhex .\FileWithEmptyLinesAtEnd.txt

Address:  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  A  B  C  D  E  F ASCII
-------- ----------------------------------------------- ----------------
00000000 73 65 72 76 65 72 31 2C 73 65 72 76 65 72 32 2E server1,server2.
00000010 64 6F 6D 61 69 6E 2E 6C 6F 63 61 6C 2C 73 65 72 domain.local,ser
00000020 76 65 72 33 0D 0A 20 20 20 20 20 20             ver3..
```

and after:

```
19> fhex .\FileWithEmptyLinesAtEnd.txt

Address:  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  A  B  C  D  E  F ASCII
-------- ----------------------------------------------- ----------------
00000000 73 65 72 76 65 72 31 2C 73 65 72 76 65 72 32 2E server1,server2.
00000010 64 6F 6D 61 69 6E 2E 6C 6F 63 61 6C 2C 73 65 72 domain.local,ser
00000020 76 65 72 33                                     ver3
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to do anything..? The file is not touched.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure how applicable this is to the situation but my google search for removing the last line of a text file led me here and the above examples/solutions didn't work.  This is the command I was able to use to get this to work:

```
$file = "file.txt"
Get-Content $file | Measure-Object -Line
$a = (Get-Content $file | Measure-Object)
(Get-Content $file) | ? {($a.count-1)-notcontains $_.ReadCount} | Set-Content $file
```

If you are working with a large file you may want to pipe this to a temp file first.

Comment: This would appear to remove the second to the last line.  Changing {($a.count-1) to {($a.count-0) allows it to "remove" the last line.  Adjust that number to the desired count to remove a specific line number from the bottom up.  Just remember the first (bottom) line is 0 in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

For 'UCS-2 Little Endian' file format, use this:

```
$stream = [IO.File]::Open($filename, [IO.FileMode]::Open)
$stream.Position = $stream.Length - 4
$bytes = 0..3 | %{ $stream.ReadByte() }
$compareBytes = 13,0,10,0 # CR,LF
echo "bytes: "$bytes
if ("$bytes" -eq "$compareBytes")
{
    $stream.SetLength($stream.Length - 4)
}
$stream.Close()
$stream.Dispose()
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this, though it will remove ALL empty lines from your file

```
(Get-Content c:\FileWithEmptyLinesAtEnd.txt) | 
Where-Object {$_ -match '\S'} | 
Out-File c:\FileWithEmptyLinesAtEnd.txt
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that will still put a closing CRLF on the last line of the file.