# In PowerShell how to replace carriage return

Tags: powershell, replace, carriage-return

In a PowerShell script I'm exporting data read from a SQL Server query into a .csv file tab delimited. I need to remove any carriage return characters.

`` -replace '`r`n' `` isn't working.  I think the character is `char(13)`.

Here's my code line that doesn't work:

```
(Get-Content $MyCSV_DOR) | % {$_ -replace '`r`n', " "} | out-file -FilePath $MyCSV_DOR -Force -Encoding ascii
```

I've also tried the below:

```
`r, `n, \r, \n and \r\n
```

All of them fail to remove the character. I've also looked at the suggested other posts.

Are there any suggestions?

Comment: Did you try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19127741/replace-crlf-using-powershell)

Comment: Single quoted strings don't accept escaped characters, only double quoted ones, so that would need to be `"\`r\`n"`, however `get-content` doesn't output any strings with line breaks because it breaks the file up on line breaks itself, and outputs individual lines. You need `get-content -raw` to read the entire file into the pipeline as one string including linebreaks

Comment: `(Get-Content $MyCSV_DOR) -replace "\`r\`n" | Set-Content -Path $MyCSV_DOR -Force -Encoding ascii`

Comment: I always use this for linefeeds `[Environment]::NewLine`

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler you should put that as an answer to the question +1

Answer (score 5):

By default, `get-content` automatically splits a file into lines on newlines and if `out-file` receives an array of lines, it puts the newlines back. So your `-replace` does nothing because the newlines have already been removed by `Get-Content`. You need to use the `-raw` parameter to read the file as a single block of text. The following should do what you want

```
(Get-Content -Raw $MyCSV_DOR) -replace "[`r`n']+, ' ' | 
     Out-File -FilePath $MyCSV_DOR -Force -Encoding ascii -nonewline
```

Note: I changed the replace pattern to replace any sequence of one or more of carriage return or newline characters by a single space

Answer (score 0):

Use Regex matching: -replace "[\r\n]"," "