# Replacing CRLF with LF newline control characters in PowerShell Format-Table output

Tags: powershell

I have been attempting to replicate the output of the Unix command `find . -type f -exec md5sum {} +` to compute hashes for all files in a directory and its subdirectories in PowerShell (i.e. two columns: MD5 hashes in lowercase and relative file paths). Is there a better way to have newlines marked with a line feed instead of a carriage return and a line feed than in the following code?

```
$Result = Get-FileHash -Algorithm MD5 -Path (Get-ChildItem "*.*" -Recurse) | Select-Object @{N='Hash';E={$_.Hash.ToLower()}},@{N='Path';E={$_.Path | Resolve-Path -Relative}}
($Result | Format-Table -AutoSize -HideTableHeaders | Out-String).Trim() + "`n" -replace ' *\r\n',"`n" | Set-Content -NoNewline -Encoding ascii $ENV:USERPROFILE\Desktop\MYFOLDER\hashes.txt
```

The first line returns the hashes in lowercase and the relative paths.

The second line uses `Format-Table` to exclude the column headings (with the option `-HideTableHeaders` plus it uses the option `-AutoSize` to avoid truncating long relative file paths).

`Out-String` converts the output to a string and `.Trim()` removes the preceding and trailing blank lines.

Presently, I add a line feed

```
`+ "`n"`
```

then use

```
`-replace ' *\r\n',"`n"`
```

to do the replacement and eliminate any extra spaces at the end of each line. Finally, `Set-Content` uses the option `-NoNewline` to avoid a newline with a carriage return.

I've seen these similar questions: [Replace CRLF using powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19127741/replace-crlf-using-powershell)
and
[In PowerShell how to replace carriage return](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50284531/in-powershell-how-to-replace-carriage-return)

Comment: What is the question? A better place to present working code is [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Nevrtheless a one liner `(Get-FileHash -Algorithm md5 -Path (Get-ChildItem "*.*" -Recurse)|ForEach-Object{"{0}  {1}" -f $_.Hash.ToLower(),(Resolve-Path $_.Path -Relative)}|Out-String) -replace '\r(?=\n)'|Set-Content -NoNewline -Encoding Ascii sample.md5`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of replacing all `"\r\n"` newlines afterwards, this approach builds a list of strings and joins them together with the wanted newline character:

```
$path = 'YOUR ROOT DIRECTORY'
$algo = 'MD5'

$list = Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -File -Recurse | Get-FileHash -Algorithm $algo | ForEach-Object {
    "{0} {1}" -f $_.Hash.ToLower(), (Resolve-Path $_.Path -Relative)
}
Set-Content -Path 'D:\checksums.txt' -Value ($list -join "`n") -NoNewline -Encoding Ascii -Force
```

Another way of doing this could be to use a `StringBuilder` object together with its `AppendFormat` method:

```
$path = 'YOUR ROOT DIRECTORY'
$algo = 'MD5'

$sb = New-Object -TypeName System.Text.StringBuilder
Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -File -Recurse | Get-FileHash -Algorithm $algo | ForEach-Object {
    [void]$sb.AppendFormat("{0} {1}`n", $_.Hash.ToLower(), (Resolve-Path $_.Path -Relative))
}
# trim off the final "`n"
$sb.Remove($sb.Length -1, 1)

Set-Content -Path 'D:\checksums.txt' -Value $sb.ToString() -NoNewline -Encoding Ascii -Force
```