# REMOVE FIRST LINE from TEXT file AFTER running a script in POWERSHELL

Tags: powershell

I've put a script together that captures all the computers in an active directory and imports that list into a .txt file. This works fine, however, when I open the .txt file I noticed that the first line is blank.. I referred back to my code and saw that I've got my table headers set to "-HideTableHeaders" when I removed this, it displayed the table header.. my question is how do I remove th table header completely and start the generated results from the FIRST LINE.. instead of having a header there or a blank line. See code below:

```
$location = // location where I save my outputfile
Get-ADComputer -Filter [Name -like "test*" } - Property * | Format-table Name -auto -HideTableHeaders | out-file $location
```

Things I've tried:

1) Removed "-HideTableHeaders"

2) Tried adding "select-object -skip 1"

I don't think its a major issue having the first line blank or having a header name, its just for personal knowledge, I want to know how to set the output result so it starts from the FIRST line.

Help will be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Sohail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rule number 1 in PowerShell, never do formatting in the middle of your code. Keep the formatting CmdLets for last. So in this case you don't need to use `Format-Table` as it breaks the pipeline and is only useful for visual representation in the console, not for output to files:

```
$location = 'S:\Test\Out_Test\File.txt'

Get-ADComputer -Filter {Name -like "Test*"} -Property * | 
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name | Out-File $location
```

Comment: You sir are a genius! Thank You!

Comment: What if I want to remove the white space from the last line?

Comment: That's a tricky one, the answer is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11643043/remove-last-line-from-file-with-powershell). It looks a bit of a hassle to do that. If it's not really needed, I wouldn't be bothered with it. Don't forget to mark as solved.

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate it.. and definitely... I'll be marking you as my question solver lol :) have a nice day.

Comment: You're welcome :) Keep exploring, the more you use it the better you get at it.