# Set-Content will make new file but won't replace old one

Tags: powershell, input, output

I have a Powershell script that keeps track of an inventory text file. I want to update the text file with the script. The following line will remove an item from the inventory as requested by the user:

```
Get-Content inventory | Where-Object {$_ -notmatch "$removed"} | Set-Content inventory.new
```

It works just fine, but I want to update the *original* inventory file, i.e. I don't want to make an "inventory.new," I just want to update "inventory." If I replace `inventory.out` with `inventory` I am presented with the following error:

```
Set-Content : The process cannot access the file 'path\inventory' because it is being used by another process.
```

The funny thing is that I *am* able to remove `inventory`, then rename `inventory.out` to `inventory`. Again, this works but isn't ideal. I felt silly just testing it. There must be a more elegant solution!

Comment: Enclose the gc in parentheses so the file is processed and released before piping `(Get-Content inventory) | Where-Object {$_ -notmatch "$removed"} | Set-Content inventory.new`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding of it is that when you open the file with Get-Content, the file is in use until the end of that command, so it won't let you make changes until Get-Content lets go of the file.

An easy workaround might be:

```
$inventory = Get-Content inventory | Where-Object {$_ -notmatch "$removed"}
$inventory | Set-Content inventory
```

Comment: It works, and thank you for the explanation. This does add a newline to the end of my inventory file (well to be fair, it did it before, too). Does Powershell have a method to chomp the last newline so that the final line in the file contains a legitimate entry?

Comment: @Reubens4Dinner You might read this [acrticle to the topic](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2015/08/07/the-powershell-5-nonewline-parameter/) or the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11643043/remove-last-line-from-file-with-powershell)