# removing extra space in last row using ssis

Tags: sql-server, csv, ssis, etl

I have a csv file which contains few rows, columns. I am having issue at source because the  last row has an extra space. How can i remove this space?

*You can see the following image has an extra space at the end*

[image: you can see the attached image has an extra space at the end]

Comment: What is the source of this file?  If this be a one-off requirement, I might be OK with just manually editing that last and removing the whitespace.

Comment: Are you open to non-ssis ideas? Like, powershell? I'm assuming your `BULK INSERT` is breaking? Also is it a single file or multiple files?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - unfortunately this is a weekly produced file and the source is  being not controlled by our team it has become an issue.

Comment: @scsimon I am ok to powershell (i guess i can run this using execute process task). Yes the DFT is failing at source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are open to powershell, I have used this method. It's important that the last think in each file is your `LF/CR`. If it could be *missing* then you'd have to put a check in there for that.

Single File

```
$stream = [IO.File]::OpenWrite("somefile.csv")
$stream.SetLength($stream.Length - 2)
$stream.Close()
$stream.Dispose()
```

Multiple Files in a directory

```
#Remove the last bit of data from the end of the file, which is a LF, so BULK INSERT doesn't break
$fileDirectory = "E:\dir\subdirectory"

foreach($file in Get-ChildItem $fileDirectory)
{
    $filePath = $fileDirectory + "\" + $file

    $stream = [IO.File]::OpenWrite($filePath)
    $stream.SetLength($stream.Length - 2)
    $stream.Close()
    $stream.Dispose()
}
```

I use this on a pretty large daily dataset and it's stupid fast, a second or two. Original idea credited to [Joey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/73070/joey) via [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11644795/6167855)

**FROM THE OP**

[image: Execute process Task Values]

Comment: awesome @sqlvan glad to help!