# Powershell to replace text in multiple files stored in many folders

Tags: file, powershell, replace, directory

I want to replace a text in multiple files and folders. The folder name changes, but the filename is always config.xml.

```
$fileName = Get-ChildItem "C:\config\app*\config.xml" -Recurse
(Get-Content $fileName) -replace 'this', 'that' | Set-Content $fileName
```

When I run the above script it works, but it writes the whole text in config.xml about 20 times. What's wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PowerShell Script to Find and Replace for all Files with a Specific Extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2837785/powershell-script-to-find-and-replace-for-all-files-with-a-specific-extension)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

$filename is a collection of `System.IO.FileInfo objects`.
You have to loop to get the content for each file :
this should do what you want :

```
$filename | %{
    (gc $_) -replace "THIS","THAT" |Set-Content $_.fullname
}
```

Comment: Note: this seems to set the content of all files, i.e. image files will be opened as text and re-saved.  I added an additional check before modifying files

Comment: The text "THIS" can contain a regular expression as well. So, if you want to replace a literal string "THIS+" with "THAT+" then you need to escape the + in the source string. E.g. "THIS\+","THAT+"

Answer (score 12):

In general, you should use the pipeline and combine the `ForEach-Object` and/or `Where-Object` CmdLets.

In your case, this would like like something more akin to:

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\config\app*\config.xml" -Recurse | ForEach-Object -Process {
    (Get-Content $_) -Replace 'this', 'that' | Set-Content $_
}
```

Which can be shortened somewhat to:

```
dir "C:\config\app*\config.xml" -recurse |% { (gc $_) -replace 'this', 'that' | (sc $_) }
```

Comment: Nice.  Thanks for the showing both the long and shorthand.

Answer (score 7):

$filename is an array of filenames, and it's trying to do them all at once.  Try doing them one at a time:

```
$fileNames = Get-ChildItem "C:\config\app*\config.xml" -Recurse |
 select -expand fullname

foreach ($filename in $filenames) 
{
  (  Get-Content $fileName) -replace 'this', 'that' | Set-Content $fileName
}
```

Comment: How would I count the number of files changed and/or number of changes made?

Answer (score 0):

I got list of files to replace text this way.

$filenames = Get-ChildItem|Select-String -Pattern
""|select Filename

This gets 12 files.

To replace this text in all files

foreach ($filename in $filesnames){ (Get-Content $filename.Filename) -replace "", ""|Set-Content $filename.Filename }

Don't forget last part for Filename. $filename.Filename

Comment: $filenames = Get-ChildItem|Select-String -Pattern "<script src='jquery.js'></script>"|select Filename