# Visual Studio how to update several csproj files

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, frameworks

I need to upgrade my framework. Following [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28436066/retargeting-all-projects-in-a-solution-to-net-4-5-2) with the "Replace in files command" I replaced all

```
targetFramework="net452" ---> targetFramework="net472"
```

and that worked. But when it comes to replace

```
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5.2</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```

in `*.csproj`, it seems not to find anything despite having include all files and even the external ones.

[image]

Comment: How about searching for `<TargetFramework>net452</TargetFramework>`?

Comment: It doesn't work either. And besides, the content of the csproj file is the one in the picture. It seems that VS doesn't search in those files

Comment: which VS version you have? @Luca

Comment: Is that VS2019? I remember having had trouble with Find&Replace in "Entire solution". Try a directory path instead.

Comment: Think there's an extension for this... I'm sure I have it installed somewhere..

Comment: VS2022. And yes I have also tried the directory path but it doesn't work. I see it takes some time for searching but the search returns 0 found items. That even if I search a simple char "a" in all .csproj files

Comment: It's called Target Framework Migrator : https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=PavelSamokha.TargetFrameworkMigrator

Comment: Thanks I tried that already but it says it is not compatible

Comment: If you (or a colleague) has got vs2019 installed, give it a go in that. Source code is available too; can give a try at downloading it and building it for 2022.