# Is there a way to programmatically modify a report in SCCM 2012?

Tags: wmi, sccm, wql

I am part of a team that is working on moving over our existing SCCM system from 2007 to 2012. The reports have been migrated over, but most of the queries do not work due to inconsistencies in the table and column names.

As a result, I need to modify the migrated reports to reflect the table and column names in SCCM 2012. There are over 1000 reports, so I would like to script this process.

Is there a way to modify an SCCM report programmatically, via WMI, instead of through the SCCM console?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a powershell script that can find/replace text in multiple files:

[PowerShell Script to Find and Replace for all Files with a Specific Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2837785/powershell-script-to-find-and-replace-for-all-files-with-a-specific-extension)

Perhaps you could copy all the rdl files from their location on the existing MSSRS server (for me it's X:\SMS_SRSRP\Reports) to a temporary location, modify them with a variation of the script above (doing multiple find/replace loops for each DB item that needs to be changed), and then copy the modified files to your new MSSRS server.

Comment: You should add the code here in case the linked page changes. The link should be also given, but just for reference purposes.