# Powershell - Search & Replace - First Matched Text String Occurance - Save Output Files

Tags: string, powershell, search, replace

I am trying to replace only the first **occurrence** of a string found within a bunch of text files. I have spent hours on this and can't seem to fix it.

I couldn't get this to work. [PowerShell Script to Find and Replace for all Files with a Specific Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2837785/powershell-script-to-find-and-replace-for-all-files-with-a-specific-extension)

```
$text_file_ext = 'txt'
Get-ChildItem $base_dir -Recurse -Include "*.$text_file_ext" |
ForEach-Object { (Get-Content $_.FullName) | 

foreach -Begin { $found = $false; $search = 'APPLE' } -Process {
if (! $found -and ($_ -match $search))
{
    $_ = $_ -replace $search, ' COFFEE'
    $found = $true
}
#$_
Set-Content $_.FullName}
}
```

I also referenced this: 
http://www.adamtheautomator.com/use-powershell-to-do-a-findreplace-on-a-set-of-text-files/

Sample Text

Lorem ipsum **APPLE** dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec a pharetra nisl, vitae **APPLE** vehicula turpis. Aenean eleifend bibendum quam, nec dapibus felis viverra ut. Mauris nec nibh scelerisque, aliquet ligula in, viverra justo. Interdum et malesuada fames ac **APPLE** ante ipsum primis in faucibus.

Any advice is appreciated.

**Final Version Working**

```
$search ="APPLE"
$text_file_ext = 'txt'
Get-ChildItem $base_dir -Recurse -Include "*.$text_file_ext" |
ForEach-Object { (Get-Content $_.FullName -Raw) -replace" (.+?)$search(.+)",'$1COFFEE$2'|
Set-content $_.Fullname
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be easier if you can deal with the file as a single string.

If you have V3 or better you can add the -Raw switch:

```
(Get-Content $_.FullName -Raw)
```

For earlier versions, you can pipe through Out-String:

```
(Get-Content $_.FullName | Out-String)
```

Then user a regex with a lazy match:

```
(Get-Content $_.FullName -Raw) -replace "(.+?)$search(.+)",'$1COFFEE$2'|
 Set-content $_.Fullname
```

Comment: `Set-Content` will add extra newline at the end of file.

Comment: Thank you Gentlemen for your help I have done this :                 $search ="APPLE"
$text_file_ext = 'txt'
Get-ChildItem $base_dir -Recurse -Include "*.$text_file_ext" |

ForEach-Object { (Get-Content $_.FullName -Raw) -replace "(.+?)$search(.+)",'$1COFFEE$2'|
 Set-content $_.Fullname - I am sure it is not right the way I am writing it?

Comment: Are you not getting the expected results?

Comment: Thankyou mjolinor - it replaced the first occurrence as it was meant to . Great work :)

Comment: Just a quick follow up  - if I wanted to replace the first occurrence as brackets ()    -  I have done   $search ="\(\)"  - it replaced all the brackets -  any way I can have the first set of brackets only thank you

Comment: Try running $search through [regex]::Escape() first -> $search = [regex]::excape($search).

Comment: For Some reason it replaces the first 2 sets of () brackets it finds  - but leaves the rest alone - I'm not sure what it could be

Comment: Post another question, including your code and sample data.

Comment: $search ="()"
$search = [regex]::Escape($search)
$text_file_ext = 'txt'                     
Get-ChildItem $base_dir -Recurse -Include "*.$text_file_ext" |
ForEach-Object { (Get-Content $_.FullName -Raw) -replace "(.+?)$search(.+)",'$1COFFEE$2'|   
Set-content $_.Fullname} - thank you -Sample data same as above but () instead of APPLE