# get-childitem variable return empty value

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-3.0

I'm trying to figure out why, my `Get-ChilddItem` variable is returning an empty $null value while running the below scriptblock, whereas from ISE, if i enter variables values manually, i'm able to get an output of the .sql files I've selected before the `Get-ChildItem` command. Below is a beginning of the function i'm writing:

```
Function test{ 
[CmdletBinding()]
Param (
   [Parameter(Mandatory=$True]
   [string]$client
   )
# Define variables
$Master = 'master'
$Slave = 'slave'
$SourcePath = "C:\somefolder\folder"
$Masterfolder = "C:\somemasterfolder"
$Slavefolder = "C:\someslavefolder"

# Create folders
    $clientdir2 = New-Item -Path $Slavefolder -name "$client" -ItemType    Directory

# Create folder on secondary server
    $clientdir = New-Item -Path "Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::\\$master\somemasterfolder" -name "$client" -ItemType Directory

# Getting all sql files and copy them to the destination folder
    $gflz = Get-ChildItem $SourcePath\* -Include __07*, __08*, __10*
# Copy
    Copy-Item $gflz $clientdir2

# Replace values in each sql files 
    $cpz = @(Get-ChildItem $clientdir2\* -Include *.sql)
if ($cpz -ne $null) {               
    Foreach ($flz in $cpz) {
        (Get-Content $flz.FullName) | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace'clientID', "$client" -replace 'C:\LSpath', `
        "$Masterfolder" -replace'C:\LSPath2', "$Slavefolder" } | Set-Content $flz.FullName}}
```

Thus, the replace operation cannot take place, as it loops on nothing.
Am I writing this the wrong way for the intended purpose? 
Would you point me out to the right direction?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Figured out my problem from this Stackoverflow post [PowerShell Script to Find and Replace for all Files with a Specific Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2837785/powershell-script-to-find-and-replace-for-all-files-with-a-specific-extension).
I was pretty sure that the files property in the `Get-Content` command included *Fullname* or *Name* as member. Turns out that when I checked for the members i could not get any properties match FullName or Name:

```
Get-Content $sqlfiles | gm -MemberType Properties

     TypeName: System.String

Name         MemberType   Definition
----         ----------   ----------
PSChildName  NoteProperty System.String          
PSChildName=Mysqlfiles.sql
PSDrive      NoteProperty System.Management.Automation.PSDriveInfo PSDrive=C
PSParentPath NoteProperty System.String     
PSParentPath=C:\parentpath
PSPath       NoteProperty System.String    
PSPath=mysqlfilefullpathname.sql
PSProvider   NoteProperty System.Management.Automation.ProviderInfo      
PSProvider=Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem
ReadCount    NoteProperty System.Int64 ReadCount=1
Length       Property     int Length {get;}
```

So the only properties that relates to FullName property was ***PSPath*** as suggested in the post that i quoted above.
Defining the right properties turns out to help replace the string inside each files as i was expecting to do.
Credits to [Daniel Liuzzi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/88709/daniel-liuzzi) and [Robben_Ford_Fan_boy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/227426/robben-ford-fan-boy) for the hints.