# Prevent Powershell from adding new line at the end of file

Tags: powershell, newline

I needed to replace HTML entities in the files within several subfolders, so I used PowerShell script suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2837891

However, that script adds an extra new line to the end of file and I'd like to avoid that. There was another script listed in the very next comment in that thread (https://stackoverflow.com/a/2837887) which was supposed to achieve exactly what I need, but it didn't work when I tried running it.

Here is my script:

```
$configFiles = Get-ChildItem . *.xml -rec
foreach ($file in $configFiles)
{
    (Get-Content $file.PSPath) |
    Foreach-Object { $_ -replace '&# 8211;','–' } |
    Foreach-Object { $_ -replace '&# 160;',' ' } |
    Foreach-Object { $_ -replace '&# 8221;','”' } |
    Set-Content $file.PSPath
}
```

All I need to do is for it NOT to be adding a new line at the end.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**PowerShell v5+** supports the `-NoNewline` switch with the `Set-Content` cmdlet (and also `Add-Content` and `Out-File`).

If you're running an earlier version, you must use the .NET Framework directly, as demonstrated in [one of the answers you link to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2837887/45375).

**Caveat**: `-NoNewline` doesn't just mean that a *trailing* newline is omitted, but that *all* input objects are *concatenated directly*, without a separator (and without adding a *trailing* newline).
If your input is a single multi-line string, as below, `-NoNewLine` will work as expected, but if you have an *array* of strings you want to write with newlines only *between* them and not also a *trailing* one, you'll have to do something like:
`` (('one', 'two', 'three') -join "`n") + "`n" | Set-Content -NoNewLine $filePath ``).
See also: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45269244/45375) of mine.

---

As an aside: There's **no need for multiple `ForEach-Object` calls** or even a `foreach` statement; you can do it all in one pipeline (PSv3+, due to `Get-Content -Raw`, but you can omit `-Raw` to make it work (less efficiently) in PSv2 too):

```powershell
Get-ChildItem . *.xml -Recurse |
  ForEach-Object { 
    $filePath = $_.FullName 
    (Get-Content -Raw $filePath) -replace '&# 8211;', '–' `
       -replace '&# 160;', ' ' `
          -replace '&# 8221;', '”' |
            Set-Content -NoNewline $filePath
  }
```

---

**Optional reading:**

[TheMadTechnician](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3245749/themadtechnician) points out that an alternative to defining variable `$filePath` to refer to the full path of the input file at hand *inside the script block of the `ForEach-Object` call* is to use common parameter `-PipelineVariable` (`-pv`):

```powershell
Get-ChildItem . *.xml -Recurse -PipelineVariable ThisFile |
  ForEach-Object { 
    (Get-Content -Raw $ThisFile.FullName) -replace '&# 8211;', '–' `
       -replace '&# 160;', ' ' `
          -replace '&# 8221;', '”' |
            Set-Content -NoNewline $ThisFile.FullName
  }
```

Note how the argument passed to `PipelinVariable` must *not* have the `$` prefix, because it is the *name* of the variable to bind.
`$ThisFile` then refers to `Get-ChildItem`'s current output object in all subsequent pipeline segment(s).

While there's not much to be gained in this particular case, the general advantage of using
`-PipelinVariable` is that the variable bound this way can be referenced in *any* subsequent pipeline segment.