# Set-Content appends a newline (line break, CRLF) at the end of my file

Tags: powershell, newline, powershell-5.0

My original config file (web1.config) has no extra line and when viewed in notepad (showing all characters) looks as:

[image]

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6" />
  </system.web>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="myConnectionString" value="server=localhost;database=myDb;uid=myUser;password=myPass;" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Now, I need to apply the script to change my database name to something else which looks like:

```
 Move-Item "web1.config" "webtemp.config"
Get-Content "webtemp.config" | ForEach-Object {$_ -replace "database=myDb;", "database=newDb;"} |Set-Content "web1.config" -Force
Remove-Item "webtemp.config"
Write-Output('Settings Changed')
```

So, the new file (web1.config) generated looks as:

[image]

Notice the extra line added at the end of the file (which is completely not needed)
I tried all other options such as:

- using `out-file` api
- using .NET method `System.IO.StreamWriter`
- using `-nonewline` flag (it converts all 10 lines into single line)
- using different encoding options
- tried replacing `\r\n` to `\r` (don't work as again set-content generates the crlf always)

I'm using PowerShell v5.1.

Answer (score 72):

**tl;dr**  (*PSv5+*; see bottom for older versions):

```sh
(Get-Content webtemp.config) -replace 'database=myDb;', 'database=newDb;' -join "`n" |
  Set-Content -NoNewline -Force web1.config
```

<sup>Note: Replace `` "`n" ``  with `` "`r`n" ``  if you want Windows-style CRLF line endings rather than Unix-style LF-only line endings (PowerShell and many utilities can handle both).</sup>

---

In **PSv5+**, `Set-Content` supports the **`-NoNewline` switch**, which **instructs `Set-Content` not to add a newline (line break) after each input object**. The same applies analogously to the `Add-Content` and `Out-File` cmdlets.

In other words: **`Set-Content -NoNewline` *directly concatenates* the string representations of *all* its input objects**:

```sh
PS> 'one', 'two' | Set-Content -NoNewline tmp.txt; Get-Content tmp.txt
onetwo
```

If what you're passing to `Set-Content -NoNewline` is a *single string* that *already has embedded newlines*, you can use it as-is and get the desired result:

```sh
PS> "one`ntwo" | Set-Content -NoNewline tmp.txt; "$(Get-Content -Raw tmp.txt)?"
one
two?
```

Note that `Get-Content -Raw` reads the file *as a whole, as-is* (aside from character decoding) and the fact that the `?` appears directly after `two` implies that the file has no trailing newline.

**In your case, since you're processing input lines *one by one* (via `Get-Content` *without* `-Raw`) and therefore outputting an *array* of lines (strings), you must first join them with a newline as the *separator*** - *between* lines only - and pass the result to `Set-Content -NoNewline`, as shown at the top; here's a simplified example:

```sh
PS> ('one', 'two') -join "`n" | Set-Content -NoNewline tmp.txt; "$(Get-Content -Raw tmp.txt)?"
one
two?
```

`'one', 'two'` is a two-element string array that is a stand-in for your line-by-line processing command.

**Encoding note:**

In Windows PowerShell, `Set-Content` produces "ANSI"-encoded files by default, based on your system's legacy, single-byte code page.
To control the encoding explicitly, use the `-Encoding` parameter.

---

In **PSv4-**, a solution that uses the .NET Framework is needed:

```sh
PS> [System.IO.File]::WriteAllText('tmp.txt', ('one', 'two') -join "`n"); "$(Get-Content -Raw tmp.txt)?"
one
two?
```

Note that [`[System.IO.File]::WriteAllText()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.File.WriteAllText), in the absence of an encoding argument, defaults to BOM-less UTF-8.
Pass the desired [`[System.Text.Encoding]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Text.Encoding) encoding instance as the 3rd argument as needed.

Comment: Powershell has some interesting design decisions... Like, under what circumstances would anyone want a newline appended?

Answer (score 4):

I never noticed this, so i did a quick search and found:

[set-content adds newlines by default](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jmanning/2007/05/23/powershell-gotcha-of-the-day-set-content-adds-newlines-by-default/)

The suggested solution is to encode your content to bytes and then use Set-Content with the -Encoding parameter.

```
Set-Content test.txt ([byte[]][char[]] "test") -Encoding Byte
```

I tested it myself so i can confirm that this works.

Comment: Nice finding/answer +1. Just to mention this works the same on PowerShell 6.0.0beta4 on Linux/Darwin aside from appending only lf `0A`

Comment: This solution comes with a caveat: it essentially creates a single-byte ISO-8859-1-encoded file (ISO-8859-1 is largely, but not fully compatible with the most widely used legacy Windows code page, Windows-1252), which means
that (a) you can't select a different output encoding and (b) the solution breaks with strings that contain characters that are not part of ISO-8859-1, such as `€`:  The following command _breaks_, for instance:
`Set-Content test.txt ([byte[]][char[]] "€") -Encoding Byte`

Comment: @LotPings: This solution doesn't append _anything_, which is the point (by contrast, any line breaks _already present in the input_ are likely to be LF-only on a Unix platform). However, as stated, this solution is problematic from an encoding perspective.

Comment: @mklement0 unlucky  wording, difference is just the system specific line termination.

Answer (score 0):

I see that's an xml file.  This way doesn't add a newline.

```
[xml]$xml = get-content web1.config
$xml.configuration.appSettings.add.value = 
  $xml.configuration.appSettings.add.value -replace 'database=myDb;',
  'database=newDb;'
$xml.save("$pwd\web1.config")  # in case of .net weirdness
```