# Compare file contents with string in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to compare the contents of a text file with a string. Sounds simple, but no luck!

```
$mystring = @'
hello
goodbye
'@

set-content c:\temp\file.txt $mystring

if (Test-Path "c:\temp\file.txt") {
    $myfile = Get-Content "c:\temp\file.txt" -raw
    if ($myfile -eq $mystring) {
        write-host 'File same'
    }
    else {
        write-host 'File different'
    }
}
else {
    write-host 'No file'
}

Write-Host $mystring.Length
Write-Host $myfile.Length
```

Output

```
File different
14
16
```

The lengths of the two string are different and when you open the file, there's a new line at the bottom which is where I'm presuming the extra 2 characters in the length are coming from.

What am I missing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45266461/set-content-appends-a-newline-line-break-crlf-at-the-end-of-my-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible solution:

Add parameter -NoNewline

Making it: *set-content c:\temp\file.txt $mystring **-NoNewline***

Possible duplicate of:

[Set-Content appends a newline (line break, CRLF) at the end of my file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45266461/set-content-appends-a-newline-line-break-crlf-at-the-end-of-my-file)

Explanation:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jmanning/2007/05/23/powershell-gotcha-of-the-day-set-content-adds-newlines-by-default/

Answer (score 1):

Append  `-NoNewline` in `set-content`  command

so your full line will be

```
Set-Content "c:\temp\file.txt" $mystring -NoNewline
```

Answer (score 1):

You could remove trailing newline characters with [`String.Trim()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.trim?view=netframework-4.8#System_String_Trim) before comparing:

```
$myfile = (Get-Content "c:\temp\file.txt" -Raw).Trim()
```

Comment: The extra newline would still be in the file, which might not be expected, since it's not in the original string.