# Unable to use sed command in Windows Command Prompt due to 'unterminated address regex'

Tags: regex, windows, sed, cmd

I'm trying to run a `sed` command on a Windows machine from the command prompt (CMD.exe) but I am struggling to understand the regular expression and how to escape the string properly when running on Windows. Ideally, I want to develop a solution that works across UNIX and Windows.

`sed` is not available on Windows so I have installed it via the [gnuWin32 project](https://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm) which works well.

The unix format for the command is:

```
sed -i '' -e 's/\\/_next/\\.\\/next/g' out/**.html
```

Through a process of trial an error I have managed to get this far:

```
sed -i \'\' -e \'s/\\/_next/\\.\\/next/g\'  out/**.html
```

but I get an error:
`sed: -e expression #1, char 27: unterminated address regex`

So there's definitely something wrong with my regex, probably the escaping of various parts?
Any ideas how I might go about fixing this?

**Update**:

I'm getting the code from [here](https://css-tricks.com/nextjs-chrome-extension-starter/) where unfortunately only Linux and OSX are covered.

Comment: Try `sed -i "s/\\/_next/\\.\\/next/g" out/**.html`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks very much this worked! Really appreciate the assistance. If you'd like to write it as answer and maybe a tiny bit about where I went wrong I can accept?

Comment: Avoid cmd. It has quirky escaping rules due to legacy issues. The escape character is `^`, not `` \ ``, but sometimes a backslash is required. It also has other nasty things that don't exists in other shells. Use powershell instead which is much more powerful. You don't need sed at all: [PowerShell Script to Find and Replace for all Files with a Specific Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2837785/995714)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use

```
sed -i "s/\\/_next/\\.\\/next/g" out/**.html
```

The Windows GNU sed does not require the `''` empty argument after `-i` option, they can be safely removed.

Also, the sed command in Windows console should be used in double quotes.

Comment: there's no such thing as "Windows console". Console or terminal is the thing that displays output and is what a shell like cmd, bash, powershell, ksh... attaches to. In cmd single quote is not a special symbol but in powershell it is

Comment: @phuclv I used it to call the command prompt `cmd` window.