# Set file to 'Writable' with PowerShell

Tags: .net, powershell

I'm trying to set a few files to writable, but I'm having an issue. I have tried using:

```
 $file = "path/to/my/file.dat"
 $file = Get-Item $file 
 $file.IsReadOnly = $false
```

As well as everything listed here:

[How to Remove ReadOnly Attribute on File Using PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/893167/how-to-remove-readonly-attribute-on-file-using-powershell)

But it still isn't working, at least I don't think it is because when I check the file properties the 'Read-Only' box is still checked:

UPDDATE::

When I run:

```
$file.isReadOnly
```

it returns `$false`, but the box below is explicitly checked? Are these two different things?

[image]

I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong, or how to make it so this file is editable.

Comment: Are you sure you have permissions to the file?  Can you post exact result when you run `$file = gi '<path>'; $file.IsReadOnly; $file | Set-ItemProperty -name IsReadOnly -Val $false; (gi '<path>').IsReadOnly`

Comment: `False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False` but the properties box is check as `Read-Only` as the picture above shows. What am I missing?

Comment: Did you close and re-open the Properties window *after* setting the flag in PowerShell?  Properties windows don't refresh dynamically. They only show the state of things from when they first opened.

Comment: @splatteredbits, yes I've closed it and opened it a hundred times... Lol... Are these two different properties that I'm working with?

Comment: No.  They are the same property.  I did some testing on my computer and setting the `IsReadOnly` flag to false unchecks the checkbox on the Properties window. Check that your PowerShell script is modifying the file you think it is.  I've spent hours before wondering why something wasn't working until I realized I was looking at the wrong file.

Comment: FML... You were exactly right. I was working on the wrong file. God, I feel like an idiot. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I was about to say - that screenshot shows you haven't changed the file since 2 days ago...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This works:

```
Get-Item -Path "path/to/my/file.dat" |
    Set-ItemProperty -Name IsReadOnly -Value $false
```

Answer (score 5):

You can actually skip the first line:

```
$file = Get-Item "path/to/my/file.dat"
Set-ItemProperty $file -Name IsReadOnly -Value $false
```